# SQL Query with MIN function is Returning Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, min

I'm trying to select the estimated hours of a row with the lowest date from a table.

```
SELECT prev_est_hrs
FROM (  SELECT MIN(change_date), prev_est_hrs
        FROM task_history
        WHERE task_id = 5
        GROUP BY prev_est_hrs
);
```

However this is returning two rows, why? I thought MIN was supposed to return the lowest only?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `GROUP BY` clause. The `MIN` will return the minimum value in each group.

Also,  you are only returning the group by value from the outer SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Mitch is right. One way to get the `prev_est_hrs` for the record with the earliest `change_date`, which seems to be what you're trying to find, is with an [analytic function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#i81407):

```
SELECT prev_est_hrs
FROM (
    SELECT prev_est_hrs, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY change_date) AS rn
    FROM task_history
    WHERE task_id = 5
)
WHERE rn = 1;
```

You need to consider what should happen if you have two rows with the same date. This would pick one of them at random. If there is some other criteria you could use to break the tie you could add that to the `order by` clause. If you wanted all matching rows in that case you could use `rank()` instead; look at `dense_rank()` as well, they all have their place.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to do that:

```
SELECT max(prev_est_hrs) keep (dense_rank first order by change_date)
FROM task_history
WHERE task_id = 5;
```